# Adding corresponding elements of two arrays into third array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to let the user input the number of elements `arrA` and `arrB` should have and also making the user choose the int number they want for each corresponding element in both, `arrA` and `arrB`. Then, creating the third `arrC` with the sum of the corresponding elements in `arrA` and `arrB` and then printing `arrA`, `arrB` and `arrC`.

The output should look like this:

```
Input the length: 5
Enter a value for first array, position 0: 1
Enter a value for first array, position 1: 6
Enter a value for first array, position 2: 13
Enter a value for first array, position 3: -3
Enter a value for first array, position 4: 8
Enter a value for second array, position 0: 9
Enter a value for second array, position 1: -4
Enter a value for second array, position 2: 1
Enter a value for second array, position 3: 65
Enter a value for second array, position 4: 18
first: 1 6 13 -3 8
second: 9 -4 1 65 18
result: 10 2 14 62 26
```

This is the code I have written so far and I need help as to how would i use scanner to let the user choose the input length of `arrA` and `arrB` and the elements in `arrA` and `arrB`. This is what the code looks like so far :-

```
class ArrayArithmetic
    {
     public static void main ( String[] args )
     {
        int[] arrA   = { 11, -27,  89,  17}; 
        int[] arrB   = {-3,  24, -9, -16};
        int[] sum    = {  0,   0,   0,   0};

       for(int i = 0; i < arrA.length - 1; i++)
       {
         for(int j = 0; i < arrB.length - 1; i++)
         {
            sum[i] = arrA[i] + arrB[i];
         }
       }

       System.out.println("sum: " + sum[0]+"," + sum[1] + ","  + sum[2] + ","  + sum[3] );
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose you have only 2 arrays to make it easy and don't nest loops, when you understand this pieces of code you can wrap all the method with a new loop and create infinite arrays to sum to result if you want... but you have to  understand the basics first:

Create a Scanner and ask user for the lenght of the arrays:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
// ask user!
System.out.println("Input the length:");
int arrayLength = in.nextInt();
```

Create the arrays with given lenght

```
int[] fistArray = new int[arrayLength];
int[] secondArray = new int[arrayLength];
int[] totals = new int[arrayLength];
```

Fill fist array iterating positions from 0 to number entered by user:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i ++) {
    System.out.println("Enter a value for first array, position "+ i);
    try {
        firstArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid number!!!);
        i --;
    }
}
```

Fill second array iterating positions from 0 to number entered by user and get the sum of each pos:

```
for (int i = 0; i < in.nextInt(); i ++) {
    System.out.println("Enter a value for second array, position "+ i);
    try {
        secondArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        totals[i] = fistArray[i] + secondArray[i];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid number!!!);
        i --;
    }
}
```

And print the results:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstArray));          
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondArray));       
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(totalsArray));
```

Finally, don't forget to close your Scanner to avoid memory leaks as pointed [drgPP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2902894/drgpp) so:

```
sc.close();
```

Comment: Scanner should be closed to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do as you wanted:

```
import java.util.*;

class ArrayArithmetic
{
   public static void main ( String[] args )
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Input the length ");
      int len = in.nextInt();

      int[] arrA   = new int[len];
      int[] arrB   = new int[len];
      int[] sum    = new int[len];
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter a value for first array, position " + i + ": ");
        arrA[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter a value for second array, position " + i + ": ");
        arrB[i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arrA.length; i++)
    {
     for(int j = 0; i < arrB.length; i++)
     {
       sum[i] = arrA[i] + arrB[i];

   }


}

System.out.println("sum: " + sum[0]+"," + sum[1] + ","  + sum[2] + ","  + sum[3] );


} }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Length of arrays: ");
            try {
                //Initializing length of array
                int length = sc.nextInt();
                //Constructing our arrays based on length
                int[] arrA = new int[length];
                int[] arrB = new int[length];
                int[] arrSum = new int[length];

                //Populating our array A via a loop
                for (int i=0; i<arrA.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Values for arrA at index: "+i);
                    int value = sc.nextInt();
                    arrA[i]=value;
                }
                //Populating our array B via a loop
                for (int i=0; i<arrB.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Values for arrB at index: "+i);
                    int value = sc.nextInt();
                    arrB[i]=value;
                }
                //Call the method to calcualte our sum which will be in sum array
                arrSum = makeSum(arrA, arrB, length);

                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrSum));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    sc.close();
                }

    }

    // Method to calculate our Sum Array based on the length and the Array A and B
    public static int[] makeSum (int[] arrA, int[] arrB, int length) {
        int[] arrSum = new int[length];
        for (int i=0; i<arrA.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<arrB.length; j++) {
                arrSum[j]=arrA[i]+arrB[j];
            }
        }
        return arrSum;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is your question:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter size: ");
int size =scan.nextInt();

Integer[] arrA =  new Integer[size];
ArrayList<Integer> arrB = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
```